# My hashes are stacking unordered..What's a loop that can select them by their Hash ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, hash

My Hashes are appearing like this:

```
{"6"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"4/22/2009"},
 "0"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/27/2008"},
 "1"=>{":amount_paid"=>"80.00", ":date_paid"=>"3/27/2008"},
 "2"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"5/8/2008"},
 "3"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"6/20/2008"},
 "4"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"9/22/2008"},
 "5"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}}
```

The order matters to me when I loop through it with this:

```
params[:payments].each_with_index do |item, idx|
```

In this way I can add the dates by which ever date came before them.

Is there a loop that could find the sequence of `"0".."6"` and remain close to the same syntax?

The only other alternative I can think of is to ensure that those params get stacked in order. They come from a form like this :

```
= text_field_tag "payments[0][:date_paid]"
= text_field_tag "payments[0][:amount_paid]"
= text_field_tag "payments[1][:date_paid]"
= text_field_tag "payments[1][:amount_paid]"
= submit_tag 'punch it chewy!'
```

Comment: Note that in Ruby 1.9, hashes are ordered.  In Ruby 1.8, they are not.  If using Rails with 1.8, you can use the ActiveSupport::OrderedHash class when order is necessary.

Comment: "you can use the ActiveSupport::OrderedHash class when order is necessary", just remember that there is overhead incurred maintaining the order. It's often faster to ignore the order, then sort the keys just before retrieving the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hashes are unordered in Ruby 1.8, and ordered by insertion in Ruby 1.9.  You can sort your hash by the key by using [Enumerable#sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001480) as seen in [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217548).  What you get out isn't a Hash but an array of arrays, with the first element as the keys and the second as the values.  You will need to unpack these to get what you want similar to the `each_with_index`.

```
params[:payments].sort { |a, b| a[0].to_i <=> b[0].to_i }.each do |x|
  item = x[1]
  index = x[0]
  .....
end
```

Comment: In Ruby 1.9, `Hash` es *are* ordered by insertion.

Answer (score 1):

This has a similar syntax:

```
(0..6).each do |idx| item=params[:payments][idx]
   # ...
end
```

---

`Hash` apparently keeps keys in the order they are inserted ( http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html ), so you can re-create a sorted hash this way:

```
Hash[params[:payments].sort]
```

(Apparently since Ruby 1.9.2; maybe not in all implementations)

Answer (score 1):

Hashes are unordered. There is a gem called facets which has a dictionary object that is ordered.

You could also convert the hash to an array and then sort the array.

```
thing = {"1" => {:paid => 100, :date => '1/1/2011'}, "2" => {:paid => 100, :date => '1/12/2011'}}
thing.to_a.sort
thing.inspect
```

returns: [["1", {:date=>"1/1/1900", :paid=>100}], ["2", {:date=>"1/1/1900", :paid=>100}]]

You can then loop through the array in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted_payments = params[:payments].keys.sort.map {|k| params[:payments][k]}
```

returns an array of hashes ordered by the value of the keys, which you can then enumerate with `.each`. This is more generalized than doing (0..6), which might (or might not) be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
(0..6).each do |idx|
  item = params[:payments][idx]
end
```